# Handling key presses in GTK+ (gtkD)

Tags: user-interface, events, gtk, d, gtkd

I'm playing around with [gtkD](http://www.dsource.org/projects/gtkd) (a D binding for GTK+)

I have a `window` object, instance of `gtk.MainWindow`. I want to handle keypresses on it.

- How?
- How do I deal with special keys (e.g. arrow keys, pgup/pgdn etc)?

---

PS I know these kinds of questions can be answered with google and stuff, but I've seen much "simpler" questions on stackoverflow, so I figured asking doesn't hurt.

Plus, sometimes, basic things tend to be burried under pages of documentation.

Comment: Yeah it was actaully a slight hunt for those but executable size remains much smaller than dwt so not bloated either. Did the below answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I just tried it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code which may help

```
import gdk.Keysyms; //keys enums are defined here

private void func(Button sender)
{
    //button pressed
}

but.addOnClicked(&func);

private bool func2(GdkEventKey* ev, Widget sender)
{
    if(ev.keyval == GdkKeysyms.GDK_Tab) 
        return true; //we handle Tab ourselves and prevents default behaviour
    else
        return false; //we didnt handle it so gtk does default behaviour
}

win.addOnKeyPress(&func2);
```

Comment: Thanks! Though `&func` didn't work, as it expects a delegate.

Comment: How do you mean? I have something compiled and working right now here but in my code those are defined on my windows class and up calling the addOnClicked from the ctor. Maybe thats why.